# how to shorting code blocks in VS code with shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

it can be a silly question for you but if i'm not mistaken in VS code we can short down the code with shortcut but i cant remember that. is there anyone who knows it

[image]

Comment: that is called folding a region, search for this in the keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Ctrl+K Ctrl+0      Fold (collapse) all regions

what is that mean?

Comment: what do you see when you execute that key-combo

Comment: its kinda ridiculous, first Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+0

Comment: if you want a single keyboard shortcut for this command you can define it yourself